# Examples of a convergent/nonconvergent sequence of averages.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Say you have a sequence $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ that has a sequence of averages in the form $\{b_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ such that for all natural numbers $n$, $$b_n = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i.$$

I'm trying to figure out several examples of convergence and divergence in this setup.

(1) An example where $a_n$ does not converge but $b_n$ converges.

My thought for this is to use the sequence $(-1)^n$ for $a_n$, for which the limit of the sequence of averages would approach $0$, indicating convergence.

(2) An example where $a_n$ is bounded but $b_n$ does not converge.

My thought would be to use a sequence of $0$s and $1$s for $a_n$ such that the sequence of averages $b_n$ oscillates between $0$ and $1$. Not sure how to demonstrate the sequence $a_n$ is bounded in this case.

Comment: Your approach for (1) is correct. For (2), try using runs of 0’s and 1’s so that the averages oscillates between 0 and 1. Alternation won’t work here.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/325060/a-bounded-sequence-whose-sequence-of-averages-does-not-converge