How to prove the convergence of a certain rational numbers sequence
While studying a paper about the roulette game "Red and Black", I found the sequence
$$
s_n=\frac{1}{n}\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n x_i,
$$
where $\{x_i\}_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of numbers in $\mathbb{Z}/2$, i.e., a sequence formed by zeros and ones in any order.
My question is: how to prove that $s_n$ is always a convergent sequence?
(I tried to use Copton's Theorem, but it didn't help. Also I thought "Strong Law of Large Numbers" could be the key to a solution, but finally I think that probably it is my question which is involved in the Strong Law and not the other way around)

This is simply incorrect. $s_n$ does not have to converge, try e.g. $x_i=0$ for $n!\le i<(n+1)!$ when $n$ is odd  and $x_i=1$ for $n!\le i<(n+1)!$ when $n$ is even.

Are you sure that this is true? Unless I am mistaken, the counterexamples here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/325060/42969 can easily be modified to have $x_i \in { 0, 1 }$.

Do actually mean that each $x_i \in \mathbb{Z}/2$ where $1 + 1 = 0$? Or do you just mean that $x_i \in {0, 1} \subset \mathbb{Z}$ where $1 + 1 = 2$?

Put in simpler terms,  start out with $x_1=0$  so that $s_1=0$  Next take $x_2 = 1, x_3 = 1, ... x_{r_1}  = 1, $   so that $s_{r_1} \geq \frac{2}{3}$    Now back to $x_j = 0$  until $s_{r_2} \leq \frac{1}{3}. $  And so on forever.   Alright, $r_1 = 3 $ works .  Next $r_2 = 6$  works.   Next $r_3 = 12$  works. So far: $011000111111.$

Put it together, the sequence $r_j$  of stopping points for a run of consecutive $0$ or a run of consecutive $1$  can be taken to be $1, 3, 6, 12, 24, 48,$  and so on doubling each time  starting with the number $3$  doubling to $6$

I'm sorry. You are absolutely right!

And, Sammy Black, thanks for the question, because, yes, I was meaning ${0,1}$, where 1+1=2 but wrote $\mathbb{Z}/2$. It was a very stupid error.

the sequence I described in comment. Have $x_1 = 0. $ Then $x_2, x_3 = 1.$   Then $x_{4,5,6} = 0. $   Then $x_{7,8,9,10,11,12} = 1$  Then $x_{13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24}  = 0.$
Then $x_{25,26,...,47,48} = 1 $
$$ 011000111111000000000000111111111111111111111111  ....  and \; so \; on    $$
Or put this way:  a 0, two 1's, then 3 0's, then 6 1's, then 12 0's, then 24 1's,  and so on.
